# conda error &&vscode jupyter error :when i input ''miniconda3/bin/activate && conda activate env''

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, conda

```
>> /home/inlizard/miniconda3/bin/activate && conda activate env

/home/inlizard/miniconda3/etc/conda/deactivate.d/mpivars.deactivate.sh: line 40: syntax error near unexpected token `(
/home/inlizard/miniconda3/etc/conda/deactivate.d/mpivars.deactivate.sh: line 40: `    if grep -q "compilers_and_libraries.*mpi" <(echo $FIP); then'
```

and when i open Vscode for jupyter notebook ,there is a similar mistake like this

```
/usr/bin/which: no fi_info in (/home/inlizard/opt/PROGRAMS.330/bin:/usr/local/sac/bin:/home/inlizard/opt/GMT-4.5.18/bin:/home/inlizard/opt/mseed2sac-2.0:/home/inlizard/.autojump/bin:/home/inlizard/miniconda3/bin:/home/inlizard/miniconda3/condabin:/home/inlizard/opt/PROGRAMS.330/bin:/usr/local/sac/bin:/home/inlizard/opt/GMT-4.5.18/bin:/home/inlizard/opt/mseed2sac-2.0:/home/inlizard/.autojump/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/inlizard/bin:/home/julia:/home/inlizard/bin:/home/julia:/home/inlizard/opt/passcal/bin:/home/inlizard/opt/passcal/other/bin:/home/inlizard/miniconda3/envs/obspy/bin:/home/inlizard/opt/passcal/bin:/home/inlizard/opt/passcal/other/bin:/home/inlizard/miniconda3/envs/obspy/bin)
```

Comment: To me it looks like a problem with the `impi_rt` package. Did you recently update it? Maybe there's a problem with the latest version?

Comment: Maybe,and i have reinstall miniconda and python,and then everything is ok. Sorry for getting back to you so late.